# Masking sensitive data when indexing in spring boot hibernate search

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am using spring boot 2.0.2 and hibernate search version 5.10.2.
I have the following class as my entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "CUSTOMERS")
    @Indexed(index = "indexes_customer")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Beneficiary implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "CARD_NUMBER", length = 18)
        @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
        @SortableField
        private String cardNumber;

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "FULL_NAME", length = 60)
        @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
        @SortableField
        private String fullName;
        //Getters & setters
```

The card data is persisted in plain text but masked when displaying to fronted users. However, i would like to mask card numbers when indexing.
Currently, my index looks like this:

```
{
  "_index": "indexes_customer",
  "_type": "mypackage.Customer",
  "_id": "24",
  "_version": 3,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "24",
    "name": "Customer Name",
    "cardNumber": "1234567891011"
  }
}
```

I would like it to look more like this:

```
{
  "_index": "indexes_customer",
  "_type": "mypackage.Customer",
  "_id": "24",
  "_version": 3,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "24",
    "name": "Customer Name",
    "cardNumber": "1234******1011"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: PCI standards say you're not allowed to store card numbers in a database!! Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: These are dummy card numbers so i would not mind storing  the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can index any property, including @Transient properties; these could contain custom code of yours.

```
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CARD_NUMBER", length = 18)
    String getCardNumber(){ ..}

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES, name="card_number")
    @SortableField
    @javax.persistence.Transient
    String getIndexedCardNumber() {
         return maskCardNumber( getCardNumber() );
    }
```

Alternatively, a bit more sophysticated but you could implement a custom `Analyzer` to do this. The Analyzer approach would have some impact on query results though - so it depends on what query requirements you have.

To be honest I'm surprised you want to index card numbers at all.